# Bases and Matricies

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $ dim V = 2 $ and $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is a basis of $V$. Suppose that 
$$ M(T,\{e_1,e_2\}) = \left (\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right) $$

Find a basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ of $V$ such that

$$ M(T,\{v_1,v_2\}) = \left (\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

I have two matrices given and but I don't know how to link these two matrices of $\{e_1,e_2\}$ to find the another basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$.

Is basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ in following from: $v_1=a_1*e_1+a_2*e_2$ and $v_2 = a_1*e_1+a_2*e_2$.

Direct me how to start off and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** because of the matrix,
$$
Te_1 = M(1,1)e_1 + M(2,1)e_2 = e_2
\\
Te_2 = e_2
$$

---

so you want a basis $(v_1,v_2)$ such as
$$
Av_1 = 0
\\
Av_2 = v_2
$$

For $v_2$ you can take $e_2$. 
Now let us try $v_1 = e_1 + ae_2$. For each value of $a$ $(v_1,v_2)$ is a basis because the matrix 
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0  \\
  a & 1 
 \end{matrix}\right)
$$ is always invertible.

In this case.
$$
Av_1 = Ae_1 + aAe_2 = e_2 + ae_2
$$so 
$$Av_1 =0 \iff a=-1
$$

and you can take $$\begin{cases}
v_1 = e_1 -e_2\\
v_2 = e_2
\end{cases}$$

Comment: $T(v_1) = 0.v_1 + 0.v_2 = 0$ and $T(v_2) = 0.v_1 + 1.v_2 = 1.v_2$. and how do I continue? thanks in advance!

Comment: $v_2 = e_2$ should be ok. Now try to find $v_1$ so that: 1. $(v_1,v_2)$ is a free family; 2. $Tv_1 = 0$.

Comment: so you set $T(e_2)=T(v_2)$ to get $v_2=e_2$? then $Tv_1=Te_1$?

Comment: no. what I say is thatin order to get $Tv_2 = v_2$ you **can** take $v_2 = e_2$. Then, try (for example) $v_1 = e_1 + a e_2$ (so that $(v_1, v_2)$ is free) and find $a$ so that $Av_1 = 0$

Comment: @needhelp I added the complete solution.